# Git bash not in sync with git in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-bash, visual-studio-2019, git-for-windows

Just upgraded my git bash client (to 2.23) as well as Visual Studio (to 2019) and for some reason, my git bash is not in sync with VS's git.  In git bash, when I checkout a new branch in my current project, it creates it and goes to it.  However I don't see this new branch in VS.  I have to create the new branch in VS and when I make edits to code in this new branch, my git bash does not see the changes.  It's like git bash is working on an entirely different git repo that is out of sync with what VS sees.  I'm fairly certain my git bash is incorrect since the branches shown in VS look to be correct.

Is there a way to sync git bash to that of VS so they're working off the same repo?

Comment: Sounds like you are working on two separate repos. Are you **absolutely** sure you are working on the same directory/repo?

Comment: all i do is go to my project which is hitting a local repo.  there is no other repo to look at

Comment: btw, this is an existing project i'm working on.  When I upgraded git bash and go to that project's root directory, it already sees its on "master"-- so I assume it recognizes the local git repo.

Comment: You could have multiple checkouts of the same repo

Comment: I am having a similar issue, in that Visual Studio generally will reflect the changes I've made to local working copies - however this has begun to have problems in the past few weeks.  Either changes to not appear in the Team Explorer, or staged changes do not appear to be staged.  I have found that closing VS and reopening syncs things back up.  I am suspecting a bug in VS2019.  I am  using Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.6.5, and git version 2.28.0.windows.1